# Converting simple Android project to run in Xcode

Tags: android, xcode

long time lurker first time poster

I have a simple android project which I have been asked to get running on iOS. I am not a programmer at all, just a network guy that is to quick to volunteer for tasks...

So, this is what I have been given to work off (in an eclipse project):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Add Click listeners for all buttons
    View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View thirdButton = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View fourthButton = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    fourthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View fifthButton = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    fifthButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

 // Process the button click events
public void onClick(View v) {

    //based on the button clicked display associated html file
    //html files are located under the assets folder
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            j.putExtra(Webscreen.URL, "file:///android_asset/deliver.html");
            startActivity(j);
        break;

        case R.id.button2:
            Intent k = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            k.putExtra(Webscreen.URL, "file:///android_asset/return.html");
            startActivity(k);
        break;

        case R.id.button3:
            Intent l = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            l.putExtra(Webscreen.URL, "file:///android_asset/updating.html");
            startActivity(l);
        break; 

        case R.id.button4:
            Intent m = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            m.putExtra(Webscreen.URL, "file:///android_asset/repair.html");
            startActivity(m);
        break;  

        case R.id.button5:
            Intent n = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
            n.putExtra(Webscreen.URL, "file:///android_asset/vendor.html");
            startActivity(n);
        break;  
    }
```

So all that does is show 5 buttons on screen and when clicked they open a local html file.

Anyone have some good examples to look at to do something similar in Xcode? I am trying to work with a Web view but I am not having too much luck as of yet. I managed to get something sort of working with scoreboards but this app has to be valuable in previous versions of iOS and not just 5.0.

Thanks in advance for any/all help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are saying you are not a programmer at all... So I don't even know where to start. The easiest way would be to simply open these html files in Safari. All you would need is a html server with the html files. This is how you can do it:

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:///yourdomain/deliver.html"];
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

If you want to use a webView, this is how you load files into the view:

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"deliver.html" inView:self.webview];
```

You can add your html files into your project by simply drag and drop them on your navigator list on the left side of Xcode. A sheet will appear. Remember to select "copy file..." and check the box next to your target.

The webView variable is the webview you defined in Interface Builder. You set this up using outlets:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingOutlet.html

**Edit:** Using actions you can trigger methods when clicking on a button.
Here you can learn more about actions:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html